# SQLite WAL-mode, in-memory, database with private cache?

Tags: sqlite, vfs, wal

I am working on a project which relies on the read snapshot isolation that the WAL journal mode provides in Sqlite.  It uses multiple connections to the same database to allow concurrent readers and a single writer.

For testing, I would like to use an in-memory database, but as far as I can tell, that requires `SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE` (which invalidates the read snapshot isolation guarantee that WAL mode provides).

**Is there any way to open multiple connections to an in-memory, WAL mode, SQLite database in private cache mode?**

Is there possibly a (pre-existing) VFS solution to this problem?

[WAL-mode docs](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAL mode does not apply to in-memory databases.

To get WAL (and read snapshot isolation), you need to use a temporary database on disk.
(This disk could be a RAM disk.)

Comment: Is there any way to get read snapshot isolation on an in-memory database?